# Is $\displaystyle \inf_{x \in \operatorname{rint}(C)} \sup_{y \in C} \|x-y\| = \inf_{x \in C} \sup_{y \in C} \|x-y\|$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In a linear normed space $X, $ for a set $C \subset X$ can we prove that 
$$\inf_{x \in \operatorname{rint}(C)} \sup_{y \in C} \|x-y\| = \inf_{x \in C} \sup_{y \in C} \|x-y\| \text{?}$$

Also, can we prove that $$\sup_{x \in \operatorname{rint}(C)} \inf_{y \in \operatorname{rbd}(C)} \|x-y\| = \sup_{x \in C} \inf_{y\in \operatorname{rbd}(C)} \|x-y\|?$$

or what condition can we put on $C$ to satisfy both these two equalities?
I think if we suppose $C$ is closed then the second equality is satisfied

$\operatorname{rint}(C)$ is the interior of $C$ and $\operatorname{rbd}(C)$ is the boundary of $C$ each taken w.r.t. the flat space generated by the set $C.$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please define  *rint* and *rbd*?

Comment: rint(C) is the relative interior of C i.e. the interior of C with respect to the flat space generated by the set C.
Also rbd(C) is the relative boundary of C i.e. the boundary of C with respect to the flat space generated by C

Comment: Thank you for *rint*.

Comment: Do you want $C$ to be a nearly convex set?

Answer (score 1):

A metric generalization works for the first question. Let $\ (X\ d)\ $ be an arbitrary metric space. Let $\ \emptyset\ne D\subseteq X.\ $ Define two functions $\ \gamma\ \delta: X\rightarrow\mathbb R\ $ as follows:

$$ \forall_{x\in X}\quad \gamma(x)\ :=\ \inf_{y\in D} d(x\ y) $$

and, this time assuming that $\ D\ $ is bounded (the case which you have addressed):

$$ \forall_{x\in X}\quad \delta(x)\ :=\ \sup_{y\in D} d(x\ y) $$

Then functions $\ \gamma\ \delta\ $ are metric, meaning that:

$$ \forall_{p\ q\in X}\quad |\gamma(p)-\gamma(q)|\ \le\ d(p\ q)\ $$
and
$$ \forall_{p\ q\in X}\quad |\delta(p)-\delta(q)|\ \le\ d(p\ q)\ $$

Now, consider $\ \emptyset\ne C\subseteq X\ $ and a dense subset $\ A\ $ of $\ C\ $ (hence $\ A\ne\emptyset).\ $

Now it's simple to play the kind of equations which you consider, and similar, when $\ A:=rint(C)\ $ and $\ D:= C.\ $ The key is that functions $\ \gamma\ \delta\ $ are **metric**.

Comment: What is the conclusion of your answer? I am lost here...

Comment: Your equations hold for convex C.

Answer (score 1):

In general, **NO**: Consider $X := \mathbb{R}$ and $C := \{0,1\}$ which is compact with empty interior. Then the right-hand side is equal to $1$ while the left-hand side is equal to $+\infty$ because $\text{int}\,C =\varnothing$.

If $C$ is convex and $X$ is finite-dimensional, then the relative interior is dense in $C$ and equality does hold.